# Navigation drawer - Header View with ListView

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm currently creating and defining a navigation drawer. I want now a header view, like their on the google apps, above the item rows. I only found examples with RecyclerViews, and i dont want to use it. I have all finished with a ListView and all other stuff. Maybe someone can help me :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Use navigation drawer from support desing lib http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create `NavigationView` using android design support library without having pain to create listview or RecyclerView, its all created by android.

To add it to your project you need to add the android design support library to your project, add below line in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0
```

Check out android design support features [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

First create a header(header.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nyname"
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next create a menu resource file, the items in the menu will be the items displayed in the drawer(drawer.xml)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/first1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
            android:title="@string/string1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/second2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
            android:title="@string/string2" />
</menu>
```

Next create a `DrawerLayout` file, within the drawerlayout you can see I have included a `Toolbar` and a 'FrameLayout`. When the item in the drawerlayout is clicked you can replace fragment.

Also within it is the NavigationView with these parameters:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/header" 
app:menu="@menu/drawer"
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

`app:headerLayout` is the header.xml that we created in step 1.
`app:menu` is the menu resource item i.e drawer.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Next in your MainActivity extend AppcompatActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
............................................
```

Intialise NavigationView and call setNavigationItemSelectedListener to get click events,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment 
                case R.id.first1:
                    SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
                ...................
```

Step by step procedure to create navigationview go [here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)

How it would look:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but one problem i have left. Now i have a actionbar, and not defined my own toolbar, but now i need a style with appcompat, but when i use someone of the parents, i get the error: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference", that is called at the navigation drawer where the adapter is set. Do u have any solve suggestions? :) Or should i create the toolbar?

Comment: Can you please post it as a separate question as lot more details are required to resolve it..Also it will gather more stackoverflows attention and they too can help..After you create it you can post the question here...

Comment: Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222855/navigation-drawer-with-appcompat-and-normal-actionbar

Comment: You can mark my answer answered if it helped you...I will look into the other question

Comment: I have posted my answer to your other question too. Please check it out. Dont forget to upvote/mark answered if it helped you

Comment: The question was "Navigation drawer - Header View with ListView"

Where is the listview added to your navigation drawer???