# Navigation drawer with AppCompat and normal actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have currently, a navigation drawer, a actionbar(no toolbar), and in the styles i defined as parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. I want to stay at actionbar, but when i use that parent, i become the following error:

```
"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.ActionBar.getThemedContext()' on a null object reference"
```

in that code:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.navdrawer_item_row,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
```

Have anyone a solve suggestion to fix?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. Change all occurrences of this in your code.

Below is the corrected code:

```
   ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
   mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        ab.getThemedContext(),
        R.layout.navdrawer_item_row,
        android.R.id.text1,
        new String[]{
                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                getString(R.string.title_section3),
        }));
```

Dont forget to import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Also in styles change the parent to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Can't use getSupportedActionBar(), "Cannot resolve method 'getSupportedActionBar()'"

Comment: it's not working for me, i tried changing it, but getSupportActionBar() method is unable to resolve

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. What actually worked is to remove:
`android:theme="...."` from `application` xml tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Hope this helps to save someone the struggle that I had.

This issue occurred when I created a Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio 2.3.3 with API 25.

Answer (score 0):

To use AppCompat themes, your activity must extend AppCompatActivity (or deprecated ActionBarActivity), and to get action bar call getSupportActionBar() method.