# How to creating a multi layer list?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, material-design

I want to create a multi later list with divider like this one below:

[image: Multi layer list]

any idea how should I make this?
I am familiar with simple RecyclerView and ListView and their adapters but still don't understand the idea behind this list!

Comment: Im trying to make a layout for you give me a few min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). You can group your items into sections and add a header to each section:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data
MySection testSection = new MySection("Test Group", testList);
MySection commSection = new MySection("Communicate", commList);

// add your sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(testSection);
sectionAdapter.addSection(commSection);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

In section_header.xml you create the layout with the section title and the divider. In section_item.xml you create the layout the item image and text.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to override the getItemViewType method of the recyclerview adapter, and differentiate between header and regular item. Then on onCreateViewHolder, inflate the correct layout depending on the type. Finally, if the need requires it, the ViewHolder itself can also do type-specific things.

To make things simpler, you can use the different layouts as view types, since they are ints. Here's an example:
https://github.com/urandom/gearshift/blob/master/gearshift/src/main/java/org/sugr/gearshift/ui/TorrentListMenuFragment.java#L1084

Answer (score 0):

i made this i made it as a rough sketch now you only have to adjust it to your liking. Hope it helps!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Import"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Gallery"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Slideshow"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/view" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Test Group"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Test"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Communicate"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Share"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<TextView
    android:padding="19dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_vulling"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: To make them clickable add: `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create this for the Navigation drawer I would say take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220504/navigation-drawer-header-view-with-listview)

menu groups makes it very simple to create groups and state tracking help change colors for selected option